# Access Input field of Stripe Payment using Playwright and C#

Tags: c#, playwright, playwright-test

I m trying to access the id of the field of card number in stripe so i can input card number using c# and playwright.
i have a screenshot of the DOM and I tried the below code but in vain. could you please advise on how to access the card number ID ?

```
 var CardNumberLocator = Page.Locator("id=Field-numberInput");
 await CardNumberLocator.FillAsync("1234123412341234");
```

[DOM of the stripe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Kgbw.png)

Comment: what happens? Does the Page.Locaotr work and the Fill fail, or what?

Comment: It can't find the ID of the input. I get this error: waiting for selector "id=Field-numberInput"

Comment: The image i embedded shows where the ID of the field. may be it is in frame

Comment: Can you share the text based html of the page to identify the element under which iframe?

Answer (score 1):

This can be caused by multiple reasons;

If it's embedded. You need to apply your logic to the [Content Frame](https://playwright.dev/docs/api/class-frame).

If it's invisible. (maybe the focus is triggered through a div click and it's hidden with CSS even if it exists on the HTML), this might be the reason why it's not working because WaitForSelector/Locator waits for the element to be visible. You can try using the [page.$](https://playwright.dev/docs/api/class-page#page-query-selector) selector, which will return the element whether or not it's invisible.

You can also trigger a `page.click(div)` on the overlayed element [the div in this case], then use `page.keyboard.type(text)`. The simulated click will make the page focus on the input. And the `keyboard.type` will be typing into the input.

Comment: Thanks. I made some progress with the code below :                                                                                var Framelocator = Page.FrameLocator("iframe").Locator(".__PrivateStripeElement");    var CardNumberLocator = Framelocator.Locator("id=Field-numberInput");  
 await CardNumberLocator.FillAsync("1234123412341234");                                                    so with the above, i thought i can access the frame and then the element but  I get the following error to be continued...

Comment: This is the error I get:                                                                                                           waiting for frame "iframe"
  selector resolved to hidden <iframe tabindex="-1" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" all…></iframe>
waiting for selector "iframe >> control=enter-frame >> .__PrivateStripeElement >> id=Field-numberInput".                              Any idea how to tweak it to work please? thanks

Comment: Try to follow the dynamic content inside the iframe. Seems like it's hidden. Make sure that you make it visible and the selectors are correct (this might require clicking on certain elements to open modals e.g.). To be precise that there are no other iframes where your Locator goes in by mistake, you can check `window.frames` in the Javascript console. And check the `page.$` method from the 3rd paragraph's last sentence in the answer I sent, I don't know how it's done in C# but the `page.$` method will work different than the `WaitForLocator` method that you're using.